# Oracle SQL Syntax - Check multiple columns for IS NOT NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

Is there a more concise syntax for checking whether multiple columns are not null? I'm looking to simplify

```
weight IS NOT NULL AND
weight_unit IS NOT NULL AND
length IS NOT NULL AND
width IS NOT NULL AND
height IS NOT NULL AND
dimensional_unit IS NOT NULL
```

into something shorter.

Using Oracle, if it's relevant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a dupe but I can't seem to locate it.

Comment: If this is likely to be a condition that you want to avoid (i.e all nulls) then I'd suggest adding NOT NULL constraints on the table and then your query will never need to check.

Comment: Agree with @DaveRlz: suggest having separate tables for `ThingWeight` and `ThingSize` respectively so that if a thing's weight is unknown/not applicable/etc then don't add a row to the `ThingWeight` table.

Comment: seems pretty easy to read and to the point the way you have it...why the need to change it to something else?

Comment: @tbone: As my SQL is currently written, I have to repeat that snippet four times - so I was looking for a prettier solution.

Comment: @DaveRlz: Sadly, the table is not under my control, and I can only read from it.

Answer (score 17):

With [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> NOT (A OR B) = (NOT A) AND (NOT B)

you save 20 chars ;)

```
NOT (
weight IS NULL OR
weight_unit IS NULL OR
length IS NULL OR
width IS NULL OR
height IS NULL OR
dimensional_unit IS NULL 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't such a syntax.

But if all of them are numeric you can use this trick:

```
weight + weight_unit + length + width + height + dimensional_unit is not null
```

Comment: That would be a bad idea if any of the columns has an index, because it would prevent the database from using the index to answer the query.  Better to stick with the AND.

Comment: In case anyone wants to translate this trick to concatenation of varchar2 or varchar columns, id won't work. In Oracle using concatenation. `A || B` will be `A` if `B` is null. So 'C1 || C2 || C3 || C4' would be not null if any one column was not null.

Comment: @sacundim - Not an issue here really. The 6 chained `IS NOT NULL` conditions is not going to be index friendly however you do it.

Comment: @sacundim this is just a brainstorming. And, as Martin said, it is not probably that an index will be used with a simple "is not null" condition. However, I'm sure that original version with many "is not null"s is better.

Comment: @MartinSmith Actually, IS NOT NULL conditions can hit indexes.  The ones that usually preclude index access paths are the IS NULL conditions.

Comment: @sacundim - That depends on RDBMS. TBH I was thinking of SQL Server where `NULL` values are stored in indexes so even if you happened to have a 6 column composite index on all the columns of interest it wouldn't really help (and if you had single column indexes a 6 way index join would likely be out performed by a scan of the whole table). I have a vague recollection that in Oracle Null values aren't stored in indexes so I guess indexes may have some possibility to be more useful here.

Comment: Oracle B-Tree indexes don't have nulls, while bitmap indexes do.  Oracle, however, also has Full Index Scan and Fast Full Index Scan access paths that in some cases can answer a query solely from indexes, without hitting a table.  And in addition, there is an index bitmap conversion access path that is able to combine multiple indexes.  It's just not a good idea to use a complex functional restriction when you can use a conjunction of primitive ones.  The database has more chances to optimize the latter—not just today's databases, but future improved versions too.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE X
   ADD CONSTRAINT C_X_NN
      CHECK (  (
               DECODE (weight, NULL, 0, 1) +
               DECODE (weight_unit, NULL, 0, 1) +
               DECODE (length      , NULL, 0, 1) +
               DECODE (width     , NULL, 0, 1) +
               DECODE (height      , NULL, 0, 1) +
               DECODE (dimensional_unit , NULL, 0, 1)
               ) = 0
            );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if ALL the columns are NOT NULL then you could Concatenate your columns first and then test once for IS NOT NULL e.g:

```
weight || weight_unit || length || width || height || dimensional_unit IS NOT NULL
```

This will check if all the values together across those fields do not come to a total of NULL.

If just testing whether there may be a NULL among them then I think your original statement from the question is still the best way to do it.

Comment: He wants that NONE of them to be NULL. What you wrote can be written better with a COALESCE (wheight,length, ...) is not null

Comment: In Oracle, the revised answer will return true if any of the values is not null, not if all the answers are not null (e.g. `'a' || null = 'a'`).

Answer (score -2):

How about this ..... 
coalesce(field1,field2,....,fieldn) is not null

I think this would serve the purpose!!!!

Comment: It would not. It is true if AT LEAST ONE of the columns is not null, the question is to test if ALL of the columns are not null.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to solve this problem,
            If all columns/variables are of type numeric or varchar2 then we can use following way in sql, pl/sql :

```
LENGTH(COL1||COL2||COL3) IS NOT NULL
```

Hope this will help you.