# Reduce the use of AND operator in Oracle while comparing multiple NULL values in different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to compare multiple column's NULL values. eg. Assume I have 3 columns in my table from which I have to find out NOT NULL values. I am using following code :

```
select * from table1 where 
column1 is not null 
and column2 is not null
and column3 is not null
```

I don't want to use this code as it uses "and" multiple times if columns goes on increasing.
Anybody have option to this in Oracle 11g ?

Comment: It was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596004/oracle-sql-syntax-check-multiple-columns-for-is-not-null

Comment: @Franek : Thanks ! But I didn't get the right way to handle this situation. Can you provide the snippet ?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with your code, and there is no alternative formulation that is any better by any reasonable standard.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment that your query is fine as is. If the columns that you are checking are all of a numeric variety then you can use Oracle's behavior with null values to your advantage to shorten the query like this:

```
select * from table 1
where 
  (
    column1 
    + column2
    + column3
  ) is not null;
```

If any of the listed columns are null then the sum will be null also. Unfortunately, if you have strings instead--null strings concatenate just fine, so the same approach doesn't work with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
COALESCE (expr1, expr2)
```

which is equivalent to

```
CASE WHEN expr1 IS NOT NULL THEN expr1 ELSE expr2 END
```

Your syntax would be

```
coalesce(column1,....,columnn) is not null
```

Comment: Would work for OR values:
`select * from table1 where 
column1 is not null 
OR column2 is not null
OR column3 is not null`
but not for AND

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is that `COALESCE (expr1, expr2)` will not let you filter out cases where `expr2` is null and `expr1` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of the COALESCE:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  column1 || column2 || column3 || column4 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This is true if AT LEAST ONE of the columns is not null. The question is to be sure that ALL columns are not null.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Rhyne answers well. If you had all string columns, your where clause could be:

```
    WHERE LENGTH(COLUMN1)+LENGTH(COLUMN2)+LENGTH(COLUMN3) IS NOT NULL
```

If  you had a mix of string and numeric:

```
    WHERE COLUMN_INTEGER1+COLUMN_INTEGER2+LENGTH(COLUMN_STRING3) IS NOT NULL
```