# PL SQL - Multiple column equality

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause, equality

I'm trying to evaluate multiple columns to save myself a few keystrokes (granted, at this point, the time and effort of the search has long since negated any "benefit" I would ever receive) rather than multiple different compares.

Basically, I have:

```
WHERE column1 = column2
AND column2 = column3
```

I *want*:

```
WHERE column1 = column2 = column3
```

I found this other article, that was tangentially related:
[Oracle SQL Syntax - Check multiple columns for IS NOT NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596004/oracle-sql-syntax-check-multiple-columns-for-is-not-null)

Comment: Some databases support that syntax but it is highly non-standard.  The `OR` version is the way to go.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, don't you mean `AND`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
x=all(y,z)
```

instead of

```
x=y and y=z
```

The above saves 1 keystroke (1/11 = 9% - not much).

If column names are longer, then it gives bigger savings:

This is 35 characters long:

```
column1=column2 AND column2=column3
```

while this one only 28

```
 column1=ALL(column2,column3)
```

But for this one (95 characters):

```
column1=column2 AND column2=column3 AND column3=column4 
AND column4=column5 AND column5=column6
```

you will get 43/95 = almost 50% savings

```
column1=all(column2,column3,column4,column5,column6)
```

---

`ALL` operator is a part of ANSII SQL, it is supported by most databases (Mysql, Postgresql, SQLServer etc.
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_all.php

---

A simple test case that shows how it works:

```
create table t( x int, y int, z int );

insert all 
into t values( 1,1,1)
into t values(1,2,2)
into t values(1,1,2)
into t values(1,2,1)
select 1 from dual;

select *
from t
where x = all(y,z);

        X          Y          Z
---------- ---------- ----------
        1          1          1
```

Comment: I am so excited to try this out tomorrow at work. I'll mark this answer correct if it works out.

Comment: It worked great! Thank you so much. I'm so excited to show this off to all my SQL "friends". I do have one question about it, though: does it have any kind of noticeable performance impact? my query **SEEMED** slower, but I didn't do any appreciable testing over data sets. (no need to analyze it, if you don't know, you've done enough already ;) )

Answer (score 3):

One possible trick is to utilize the [`least`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions099.htm#SQLRF00657) and [`greatest`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions078.htm#SQLRF00645) functions - if the largest and the smallest values of a list of values are equal, it must mean all the values are equal:

```
LEAST(col1, col2, col3) = GREATEST(col1, col2, col3)
```

I'm not sure it saves any keystrokes on a three column list, but if you have many columns, it could save some characters. Note that this solution implicitly assumes that none of the values are `null`, but so does your original solution, so it should be OK.

Comment: Will that work with a non-numeric item? Like a name/address/what-have-you?
But otherwise, thanks for the idea!

Comment: @goodguy5 yup, `least` and `greatest` should work with any ordering type (such as character types, dates, etc)

Comment: @Mureinik `col1 = col2 AND col2 = col3` has 27 characters, while `LEAST(col1, col2, col3) = GREATEST(col1, col2, col3)` has 52 charactes, so I doubt if this saves any keystroke

Comment: Ignoring `null` values and assuming that all the columns are the same data type, that should work.  But it would be heck on query performance unless you're going to create function-based indexes on those conditions.

Comment: Going ahead and marking this as the answer, though as @kordirko mentioned, I don't think it actually saves any keystrokes, but it's close enough.  
Oh well...